# Twilio with Unity 4.6 Call Returning Null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, twilio

I am using Unity 4.6 and I am attempting to make outbound calls using the Twilio API. I have build an application in Visual Studio using .NET 4.5, which is capable of making the outbound calls. The code to make the outbound call was sample code taken from Twilio documentation.

```
// Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "****";
    string AuthToken = "****";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    var request = new CallListRequest();

    var options = new CallOptions();
    options.Url = "http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHello+William%2C+thanks+for+the+call%21%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E";
    options.To = "+**********";
    options.From = "+**********";
    var call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);
```

I used stars to block out private information. When using Visual Studio the program makes a call from a number to another number. But, when using Unity the call object returns as null and the phone call is never executed. I know Unity is using .NET 2.0 as opposed to 4.5, which I imagine is where the issue lies. That said, all Twilio methods above are called without a problem.

Does anyone have an idea why the call would not execute in Unity, but would be OK in Visual Studio?

Comment: Just to provide further information - it appears that any call to client does not execute properly. Using, for example, client.ListCalls() returns null as well.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'm not super familiar with Unity, but I have a couple of ideas for you.

The Twilio .NET helper library is built using .NET 3.5, so that might be causing an issue, though if you are using the synchronous methods I think the code path there should not have anything in it that would not work in .NET 2.

Can you use a tool like Fiddler to see if the HTTP request to Twilio servers is even being made?  I've seen situations where errors will be eaten by either the Twilio library or the underlying RestSharp library if there is a transport error during the HTTP request (eg DNS resolution failure or network timeout).

If the HTTP request is being made and you see a valid JSON response coming back, then there might be an issue deserializing that response for some reason, thought I think thats pretty unlikely.

Finally, if nothing works, you can always try just making the HTTP yourself using HttpWebRequest.

Hope that helps.